# How can I hide the Github notification overlay (on Github website)

Tags: github, workflow

I'm referring to this one for the notifications within Github itself.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH8nM.png)

If I dismiss it with the `X`, it comes back if I refresh the page. I don't want to click the `Done` button because it archives the notification from my inbox and navigates away from the page I'm on.

I've tried hiding it using uBlock, but it leaves behind an empty space where it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

With a custom filter in [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) I was able to remove the notification tray and empty space.

```
github.com###notification-shelf
```